# Angular getHarness in Cypress test doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress, angular-test

I am currently trying to get component tests up and running and struggle with angular harnesses.
In my test I wanted to use the MatPaginatorHarness (but I have the same Problem with all of them) but unfortunately the async/await method doesn't work in cypress. So I tried it with the Promise.
Now I get the following error:

```
Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one 
or more cy commands in that promise.

The command that returned the promise was:

> cy.get()

The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:

> cy.log()
Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to wrap them or return your own promise.
```

The code is:

```
it('shows opens paginator', () => {
    const data: StudyStateModel[] = thirteenRows;
    const fixture = mount(DatatableComponent, {
        tableCols: TableColsConfig.STUDIES_COLS,
        tableData: data,
        activeEndpoint: apiEndpoints.STUDY
    });
    const loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    
    loader.getHarness<MatPaginatorHarness>(MatPaginatorHarness).then((paginator) => {
        
        paginator.setPageSize(10);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        cy.get('.mat-row').should('have.length', 10);
        cy.get('.mat-row').should('not.be.visible');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log(paginator);
        paginator.setPageSize(25);

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

I know I shouldn't use promises because Cypress tells me here, but I don't know how to do it else. The problem only occurs when having the cy.get functions within the promise. But I need them there because I need to work with the paginator.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You only pass a fixture into the Karma\Unit test TestbedHarnessEnvironment. There is a version for Protractor and generic Selenium included in the Angular Material CDK
https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/cdk/testing/protractor https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/cdk/testing/selenium-webdriver
I'm not familar with Cypress or if it has a harness environment for Angular Material but it is possible to create your own.